Undefined references to mpfr_*() functions when trying to use Boost Multiprecision in a CMake Project?
I want to use Boost Multiprecision in my C++ project, but I am unable to. I suspect I haven't added the correct dependencies in my root CMakeLists.txt configuration, the relevant part of which look like this:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.30.0)
project(MyProject VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(app)
add_subdirectory(test)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
find_package(MPFR REQUIRED)
include_directories(${MPFR_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)

I made sure to link the libraries for my executable in app/CMakeLists.txt:
add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE myLib)
target_link_libraries(main ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(main ${MPFR_LIBRARIES})

and for my library at src/CMakeLists.txt:
file(GLOB HEADER_LIST CONFIGURE_DEPENDS "${MyProject_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.h")
add_library(myLib SomeFile.cpp ${HEADER_LIST})
target_include_directories(myLib PUBLIC ../include)
target_link_libraries(myLib ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(myLib ${MPFR_LIBRARIES})

I have verified that both Boost and MPFR are installed on my system through the package manager.
My linter (Clangd) produces no errors when I include the necessary headers and use a multiprecision type:
#include <boost/multiprecision/mpfr.hpp>
// ...

int main() {
    IOParser<boost::multiprecision::mpfr_float_100> parser;
    // ...
}

But when I compile my program, I get several undefined references to various MPFR functions such as:
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `boost::multiprecision::backends::detail::mpfr_float_imp<100u, (boost::multiprecision::mpfr_allocation_type)1>::operator=(boost::multiprecision::backends::detail::mpfr_float_imp<100u, (boost::multiprecision::mpfr_allocation_type)1>&&) [clone .isra.0]':
[build] main.cpp:(.text+0x2dc): undefined reference to `mpfr_swap'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x30c): undefined reference to `mpfr_set4'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x386): undefined reference to `mpfr_init2'

What am I doing wrong?

You wrote add_subdirectory(app) before the find_package(MPFR) invocation that actually sets the MPFR_LIBRARIES variable.

Also, not sure where you got FindMPFR.cmake from (because it's not part of the CMake distribution) but you should prefer to link to MPFR through an imported target. CMake will immediately complain about not knowing the eg MPFR::MPFR target.

@Botje I am no expert on CMake, but I believe that since each subdirectory has its own CMakeLists.txt, this shouldn't really matter, as I link the libraries to all targets - my own library and the executable. Indeed, I tried moving the add_subdirectory() commands AFTER the find_package() commands and it still doesn't work, showing the same errors as before.

Hello, everyone. In my app/CMakeLists.txt I replaced target_link_libraries(main MPFR) with target_link_libraries(main -lmpfr) and it works now. @Botje was on the right track concerning the naming problems. Would you like to post your suggestion into an answer, so that I can accept it?

By the way, I noticed two votes to close the question. Any ideas as to why, so that I can improve it?

My close vote was because the issue was – at the end of the day – a simple mistake regarding ordering of statements.

The CMake file you found defines MPFR_LIBRARY, not MPFR_LIBRARIES. What a mess...

@Botje You can be absolutely certain that if CMake had a better documentation and I had noticed the wrong ordering (which wasn't the only mistake), I wouldn't have bothered writing the question :-) .

I don't think you can blame CMake for the inconsistency in the choice of magic variable names by third-party module authors. That's why imported targets are the recommendation: they do away with the guesswork.

Since both GMP and MPFR offer pkg-config files, you can use the built-in PkgConfig module to generate a nice modern target that will resolve both include and linker dependencies for you:
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(deps REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET gmp mpfr)

Now, in app/CMakeLists.txt you can just do:
target_link_libraries(main PkgConfig::deps)

As a bonus, the PkgConfig approach allows you to specify version bounds.

That's very neat and tidy and I marked it as accepted, so that people would see it first. Thanks.

@KotakaDanski: FYI, "I marked it as accepted, so that people would see it first" - Acceptance no longer pins an answer at the top.

Going off incomplete old questions and a github search I'd summarize as this:
MPFR (https://www.mpfr.org/) doesn't ship CMake support.
So you need to get FindMPFR from elsewhere. If your distribution packager doesn't add it, you have to ship it in your own repo:
(mkdir -pv cmake && cd cmake && wget -c https://raw.githubusercontent.com/quarkslab/NFLlib/refs/heads/master/cmake/FindMPFR.cmake)

Which downloads the following example cmake/FindMPFR.cmake:
# Copyright (c) 2008-2010 Kent State University
# Copyright (c) 2011-2012 Texas A&M University
#
# This file is distributed under the MIT License. See the accompanying file
# LICENSE.txt or http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php for terms
# and conditions.

# FIXME: How do I find the version of MPFR that I want to use?
# What versions are available?

# NOTE: MPFR prefix is understood to be the path to the root of the MPFR
# installation library.
set(MPFR_PREFIX "" CACHE PATH "The path to the previx of an MPFR installation")

find_path(MPFR_INCLUDE_DIR mpfr.h
PATHS ${MPFR_PREFIX}/include /usr/include /usr/local/include)

find_library(MPFR_LIBRARY NAMES mpfr
PATHS ${MPFR_PREFIX}/lib /usr/lib /usr/local/lib)

if(MPFR_INCLUDE_DIR AND MPFR_LIBRARY)
get_filename_component(MPFR_LIBRARY_DIR ${MPFR_LIBRARY} PATH)
set(MPFR_FOUND TRUE)
endif()


if(MPFR_FOUND)
if(NOT MPFR_FIND_QUIETLY)
MESSAGE(STATUS "Found MPFR: ${MPFR_LIBRARY}")
endif()
elseif(MPFR_FOUND)
if(MPFR_FIND_REQUIRED)
message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find MPFR")
endif()
endif()

Now, you could be adding the cmake directory to the prefix path:
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake;${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}")

Or, apparently the module path line you had already works:
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")

Now I did this for both MPFR and GMP to be more complete:

File ./main.cpp
 #include <boost/multiprecision/mpfr.hpp>
 #include <boost/multiprecision/gmp.hpp>

 #include <iostream>


 int main()
 {
     using namespace boost::multiprecision;

     mpfr_float_100 a = 1.0;
     mpfr_float_100 b = 2.0;
     mpfr_float_100 c = a + b;

     std::cout << c << std::endl;

     mpz_int d = 1;
     mpz_int e = 1;
     mpz_int f = d + e;

     std::cout << f << std::endl;

     return 0;
 }


Empty File ./app/CMakeLists.txt

Empty File ./test/CMakeLists.txt

Empty File ./SomeFile.cpp

Empty File ./src/CMakeLists.txt

File ./CMakeLists.txt
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.29.0)
 project(MyProject VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)
 #set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake:${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}")
 set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
 set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

 find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
 include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

 list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
 find_package(MPFR REQUIRED)
 include_directories(${MPFR_INCLUDE_DIRS})

 find_package(GMP REQUIRED)
 include_directories(${GMP_INCLUDE_DIRS})

 add_subdirectory(app)
 add_subdirectory(test)

 set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
 set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
 include(CPack)

 add_executable(main main.cpp)
 target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE myLib)
 target_link_libraries(main PUBLIC ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
 target_link_libraries(main PUBLIC ${MPFR_LIBRARY})
 target_link_libraries(main PUBLIC ${GMP_LIBRARY})

 file(GLOB HEADER_LIST CONFIGURE_DEPENDS "${MyProject_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.h")
 add_library(myLib SomeFile.cpp ${HEADER_LIST})
 target_include_directories(myLib PUBLIC ../include)
 target_link_libraries(myLib ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
 target_link_libraries(myLib ${MPFR_LIBRARIES})


File ./cmake/FindMPFR.cmake
 # Copyright (c) 2008-2010 Kent State University
 # Copyright (c) 2011-2012 Texas A&M University
 #
 # This file is distributed under the MIT License. See the accompanying file
 # LICENSE.txt or http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php for terms
 # and conditions.

 # FIXME: How do I find the version of MPFR that I want to use?
 # What versions are available?

 # NOTE: MPFR prefix is understood to be the path to the root of the MPFR
 # installation library.
 set(MPFR_PREFIX "" CACHE PATH "The path to the previx of an MPFR installation")

 find_path(MPFR_INCLUDE_DIR mpfr.h
 PATHS ${MPFR_PREFIX}/include /usr/include /usr/local/include)

 find_library(MPFR_LIBRARY NAMES mpfr
 PATHS ${MPFR_PREFIX}/lib /usr/lib /usr/local/lib)

 if(MPFR_INCLUDE_DIR AND MPFR_LIBRARY)
 get_filename_component(MPFR_LIBRARY_DIR ${MPFR_LIBRARY} PATH)
 set(MPFR_FOUND TRUE)
 endif()


 if(MPFR_FOUND)
 if(NOT MPFR_FIND_QUIETLY)
 MESSAGE(STATUS "Found MPFR: ${MPFR_LIBRARY}")
 endif()
 elseif(MPFR_FOUND)
 if(MPFR_FIND_REQUIRED)
 message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find MPFR")
 endif()
 endif()


File ./cmake/FindGMP.cmake
 # Copyright (c) 2008-2010 Kent State University
 # Copyright (c) 2011-2012 Texas A&M University
 #
 # This file is distributed under the MIT License. See the accompanying file
 # LICENSE.txt or http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php for terms
 # and conditions.

 # FIXME: How do I find the version of GMP that I want to use?
 # What versions are available?

 # NOTE: GMP prefix is understood to be the path to the root of the GMP
 # installation library.
 set(GMP_PREFIX "" CACHE PATH "The path to the prefix of a GMP installation")


 find_path(GMP_INCLUDE_DIR gmp.h
 PATHS ${GMP_PREFIX}/include /usr/include /usr/local/include)

 find_library(GMP_LIBRARY NAMES gmp
 PATHS ${GMP_PREFIX}/lib /usr/lib /usr/local/lib)


 if(GMP_INCLUDE_DIR AND GMP_LIBRARY)
 get_filename_component(GMP_LIBRARY_DIR ${GMP_LIBRARY} PATH)
 set(GMP_FOUND TRUE)
 endif()

 if(GMP_FOUND)
 if(NOT GMP_FIND_QUIETLY)
 MESSAGE(STATUS "Found GMP: ${GMP_LIBRARY}")
 endif()
 elseif(GMP_FOUND)
 if(GMP_FIND_REQUIRED)
 message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find GMP")
 endif()
 endif()



Which Works On My Machine(TM) using Nix packages for mpfr and gmp:


I think their question is how to link to MPFR, since they already wrote target_link_libraries(main ${MPFR_LIBRARIES}).

@MarcGlisse You're right. I focused too much on the error message. I hope I have redeemed the answer to something more useful now.

Both MPFR and GMP ship pkg-config files. You can consume those with find_package(Pkgconfig) and pkg_check_modules(deps REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET gmp mpfr). This will create a target called PkgConfig::deps that automatically sets up include and linker settings for those libraries. No need to reinvent the wheel :)

@Botje great. I went from OP's CMakeLists.txt "template" and github gave me great confirmation that loads of people use this. I'd very much appreciate the pkgconfig take on this. To be honest, the CMake ecosystem has a large documentation issue, not helped by the approaches evolving radically over time (which, granted, is also one of CMake's strengths)

@sehe Greetings. Your answer is actually what I tried to do and even the Find*.cmake files are identical. The only difference is I tried to include the directories before finding the packages. I fixed it but it still doesn't work. I will try @Botje's suggestion and see what happens. Thanks for writing this long answer.

Hello, everyone. In my app/CMakeLists.txt I replaced target_link_libraries(main MPFR) with target_link_libraries(main -lmpfr) and it works now :-D .
